# Regex split on string containing hyphenated words

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have the following string:

```
test_string = '"abc" + "def" + "-xyz - rst"'
```

I am trying to split this string based on the - or + operators only but excluded hyphenated words from this regex split. I got this far:

```
In [205]: [n.strip() for n in re.split(r'[ ]{1}[-+]', test_string) if n != '']
Out[205]: ['"abc"', '"def"', '"-xyz', 'rst"']
```

I am expecting my result to be:

```
In [205]: [n.strip() for n in re.split(r'[ ]{1}[-+]', test_string) if n != '']
Out[205]: ['"abc"', '"def"', '"-xyz - rst"']
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Don't you simply want to parse *string literals*?

Comment: Try [`re.findall(r'"[^"]*"|[^\s+-]+', test_string)`](http://ideone.com/EGvbP4)

Comment: I don't think this is completely clear on what you want to split on, but it looks like you might want to consider using a positive look-ahead.

Comment: I don't think you can split on the +/- sign as delimiters at the same time when using  double quotes to contain delimiters. The reason's are several, notably double quotes must be balanced and cannot exist in an odd state. So, unless it's validated `^[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$` it won't work. Even when validated, you can't split because you cant start in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering using `shlex`:

```
import shlex
test_string = '"abc" + "def" + "-xyz - rst"'
# Parse the string into space-separated elements treating quotes as the shell does
# lone + and - signs will be their own element
arr = shlex.split(test_string)
# remove any element that is either '+' or '-'
final_arr = [x for x in arr if x not in ['+', '-']]
```

Variables:

```
>>> print(arr)
['abc', '+', 'def', '+', '-xyz - rst']
>>> print(final_arr)
['abc', 'def', '-xyz - rst']
```